# Logging All Outgoing Web Requests

Tags: router, logging, network-monitoring

I'm looking for a way to monitor my home network and log all outgoing web requests and record the URL's and possibly even the IP of the machine/device that made the request. I've considered using OpenDNS but I'm using a 2Wire router from AT&T Uverse which means I can't perform the required DNS redirects.

Does anyone know of any software, routers, proxies I can use to accomplish the task?

Comment: If you want to log at the router you need a router that logs. If your only router is one you can't control, then you're SOL until you replace it (or inline another router before it). As-is this question is too broad, and ends basically as a product recommendation request (which are off-topic for SU).

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty simple.  Setup a proxy server and block port 80 (and 443) on your gateway/router  to all machines in your network except the proxy.  This will force everyone to browse through the proxy.  You may need to setup their browser settings once as well.

The proxy server has the ability to log which machine browsed to which URL.

The bonus is that the proxy server will also serve as a cache, so images that are common, like the GOOGLE logo, will be cached and will not require an access to the original server.

You can use any Linux to make a proxy server.